# Get user location from navigator in controller

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3, navigator

I am using navigator.geolocation.getcurrentposition to get current user's location (lat/long). Here's my function:

```
function userLocation(){

    var response = [];
    if (navigator.geolocation) {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(p){
            // on success
            response['latitude'] = p.coords.latitude;
            response['longitude'] = p.coords.longitude;

            console.log(response);

        }, function(e){
            // on error
            console.log(e);
        });

    } else {
        console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }

    return response;

}
```

It always returns empty array and i understand that the getCurrentPosition function makes asynchronous call so it is not possible to return the response.

I tried using google geocode api to get the location but that is based on user's IP address and not that accurate.

I want a function to return these lat/long. Is there any way i can get the response from getCurrentPosition in my controller function?

Comment: declare a global variable `( var pos={}; )`, populate that variable and use `promises` to return the value from the asynchronous geolocation call?

Comment: The function is asynchronous. It runs in the background, determining the position. When it has succeeded (or failed), seconds after your code hit `return response;`, that's when the anonymous function you passed will set your response.latitude and .longitude. You need to run an AJAX call right where you have `console.log(response)` and send the coords to the server using a simple GET/POST request.

Comment: @ChrisG yes that's the way to get the lat/long in controller, but what will the userLocation() function return, how to make it wait for the response from navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()? How will i know if the request is successfull?

Comment: You cannot make it wait. You start the request and tell JS what to do when it finishes, period. You need to work around the fact that geolocation requests are and always be async.

Comment: Yes that's what i am asking, can you suggest some work around?

Answer (score 1):

Place `getLocation()` function in window onload and one popup will ask to allow your location and if you allow your lattitude and longitude will be grabed.

Please use below code.

```
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
   console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'abc.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: 'latitude='+position.coords.latitude+'&longitude='+position.coords.longitude,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(e) {
        //called when there is an error
        //console.log(e.message);
      }
    });
}
```

Please refer this link to get more idea http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

Comment: I am getting the response in console but i need to access the response in controller

Comment: You can make a ajax call from that function to the method of the controller where you want to it and you can get Latitude and Longitude from the request of ajax call.

Comment: yes that's the way to get the lat/long in controller, but what will the userLocation() function return, how to make it wait for the response from navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()? How will i know if the request is successfull?

Comment: Make the ajax call from showPosition function only. The lattitude and longitude will be got in that function and you have to make ajax call from there so you will get it in the ajax request.

Comment: var result = getLocation(); what will be the value of result true/false ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do something with the result:

```
function userLocation(cb) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(p){
            // on success
            cb(null, p.coords);
        }, function(e){
            // on error
            cb(e, null);
        });
    } else {
        cb("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.", null);
    }
}
```

Now call the function like this:

```
userLocation(function(err, coords) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else {
        // do something with coords
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd parameter of `getCurrentPosition`.
Please refer following example.

```
var response = [];
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  response['latitude'] = pos.coords.latitude;
  response['longitude'] = pos.coords.longitude;
};

function error(err) {
  //
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

You can also refer the following link.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/geolocation_getcurrentposition.htm

Comment: I want to use these lat long in my controller. How can i do that?

Comment: Are you trying to use javascript variable in PHP controller?

Comment: i just want the response from this function to use in my controller. any suggestions?

Comment: Do you aware of scope operator? you have created your `var response = [];` variable locally. So it will not managed outside the functions. If you want to make it global and accessible from anywhere just declare it outside the function. 
`var response = [];`
and in the function just assign the values.

Comment: It will not work that way. getCurrentPosition makes an asynchronous call so it will not wait for the response before return